# Embed Video Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, video, embed

Hoping for some insight as I build my first app! My idea requires that I integrate different youtube videos based on different buttons that are pressed and I am wondering what the best way to do that is. Should I use an API? Or can I embed video straight into the app using lets say a WKWebVideo View? Are there drawbacks of either method? I read online that the Youtube API limits how many views are granted which seems like it could be a problem if I have many users so just wondering what the smartest way to build it is or tackle the problem. Also I'm not sure if there are any legal things to know about when building something like this? Do I need to cite the videos I incorporate into my app or do I need to do something to make sure I don't get in trouble with youtube? Would appreciate any help I could get with these questions and hope everyone is staying safe in this troubling time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, given all the variables going into this (first app, specifics pertaining to YouTube, etc) moving ahead with a web view is the best course of action. However, in terms of user experience, embedding a web page is always a step down from a proper native implementation.

I would suggest moving forward with a web view for the time being, use this as a jumping off point to learn more about software dev and iOS in the meantime, then, if you so desire, come back to it later and see if you can figure out a way to refactor your code to extract YouTube videos directly into a native playback view (which would be more than several steps up in terms of difficulty, not the least of which is due to YouTube trying to prevent that sort of thing) and improve the user experience.

Good luck and welcome to iOS dev!

Answer (score 0):

One the easiest way to embed youtube to app that I did was using WKWebView to load youtube embed URL.

I am not sure about the legal think, but I think if you still use the original video, channel, URL from the youtuber (not copying their video) it already cite them (because they still get the views and ads revenue from the video). Maybe you can add information that the video is not your intelectual properties.